# Constraint Handling Rules in SWI Prolog: What's the order of puting a constraint to the store?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, constraint-handling-rules

I am learning [Constraint Handling Rules (CHR)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chr) in swi-prolog.

I started with the tutorial from Tom Schrijvers' [Constraint Handling RulesA Tutorial for (Prolog) Programmers](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/CHR/files/tutorial_iclp2008.pdf).

The confusion part is that what's the order of putting a constraint to the constraint store?

1. p.69 shows that when a rule fires, add the body to **(front of)** query.
2. p.104 - p.106 show that normally, the order of putting a constraint to the store follows the query order. That is the second constraint (`piggy(1)`) will be placed at the right of the first constraint (`piggy(5)`) in the store.
3. p.107, according to 1, `piggy(6)` be added to the front of query and then be put to the store.
4. p.108, the strange thing happen, why `piggy(4)` be put to the front of the store (left to `piggy(6)`) ?
5. p.109 - p.110, more strange thing is that after the rule fired, `piggy(10)` be added to the store and then `piggy(2)` be added to the end of the store (right to `piggy(10)`)?

My first question is what's exactly the order of putting a constraint to the constraint store?

For example,

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).
:- chr_constraint philosophers_stone/0, lead1/0, lead2/0, gold1/0, gold2/0.
philosophers_stone \ lead1 <=> gold1.
philosophers_stone \ lead2 <=> gold2.

?- lead1, lead2, philosophers_stone.
```

Why the result of the query in swi-prolog is:

```
philosophers_stone,
gold1,
gold2
```

instead of

```
philosophers_stone,
gold2,
gold1
```

The slow motion is (in my understanding):

```
query: lead1, lead2, philosophers_stone.
store: 

query: 
store: lead1, lead2, philosophers_stone.

query: gold1
store: lead2, philosophers_stone

query: gold2, gold1 <---- added to (front of) query
store: philosophers_stone

query: 
store: philosophers_stone, gold2, gold1
```

It seems that when a rule fires, the body should be added to **(end of)** query? Is that right?

```
query: lead1, lead2, philosophers_stone.
store: 

query: 
store: lead1, lead2, philosophers_stone.

query: gold1
store: lead2, philosophers_stone

query: gold1, gold2   <---- added to (end of) query
store: philosophers_stone

query: 
store: philosophers_stone, gold1, gold2 <--- then correct
```

My second question is the order sensitive?

I mean that even if the putting orders are different, the result will eventually confluent up to reordering the stable store? Can I safely ignore this order? I know that the order of rules is very sensitive in swi-prolog's CHR implementation and they can not be ignored.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to both my memory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules, the constaint store is a multi-set. Therefore it has no ordering at all. (If it were ordered, we would call it a list, not a multi-set.)

As for your example, I also get:

```
?- lead1, lead2, philosophers_stone.
philosophers_stone,
gold1,
gold2.
```

But also:

```
?- lead2, lead1, philosophers_stone.
philosophers_stone,
gold1,
gold2.
```

Digging a bit into the source of `chr_show_store/1` and thence into `'$enumerate_constraints'/2`, it looks like the store is printed in the order that you declared the constraints. It also looks like each constraint manages its instances independently, that is, there is no central "constraint store" at all. Each constraint is associated with its own list of instances.

There is some ordering to execution: "Active constraint traverses the rules top-to-bottom to find any that fire", but some parts of this are unspecifed (page 214). So you're not supposed to write programs that are very sensitive to ordering issues.

As for the piggy example, it looks to me like the placement of the piggies is optimized for avoiding them moving around too much when the slides are presented during a talk. I don't think their placement is supposed to suggest an actual left-to-right order.

Comment: "the store is printed in the order that you declared the constraints" I didn't realize it before, thanks!

Comment: "So you're not supposed to write programs that are very sensitive to ordering issues." There are 3 kinds of "order": rules, constraints in store, constraints in query. "Rules" are sensitive, "constraints in store" are not sensitive because of multi-set, what about "constraints in query"? Do you think this order must follow Tom Schrijvers' argument in p.69, i.e. must add the body to (front of) query? or could be changeable in swi-prolog implementation?

Comment: IMO, in a pure logic programming language, we should be able to reorder goals in conjunction (especially constraints). I'm curious why Tom Schrijvers pointed out "add the body to (front of) query." Or do you think I should post another question?

Comment: I *think* the "front of" part may be true when the current active constraint is being rewritten to something else, as in `a <=> b`. If `a` was active, then `b` now becomes active, so it's added at the "front" in some sense. But if you have `a ==> b. a ==> c.`, as far as I understand (and again, it's been a while), I don't think there's any fixed rule whether `b` or `c` will become active first.

Comment: Also, in p.77, the author showed an example about `? - red, yellow, blue.` vs `?- red, blue, yellow.`,  the results are different. Therefore the order of "constraints in query" are definitely sensitive. Programmers have to design the rules very carefully.